# Using Excel- VBA to populate a table in Word and modify the color of a particular word in each cell

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have an array that has stored 6 pieces of information, one of which is storage conditions. There are four different storage conditions (-80C, RT, 2-8, -20C). I am iterating through the array and then populating an Avery Label Template, which is a table. I can populate the label template just fine, but I want to change the font/color of the storage condition word. I am having trouble isolating that particular element of the cell.

Here is what i have:

```
'populating cell with array containing information
.Cell(r, c).Range.Text = arrEl(x, 0) & " "& arrEl(x, 1) & " "& arrEl(x, 2)
.Cell(r, c).Range.Text =.Cell(r,c).Range.Text + arrEl(x, 3) + " "+ arrEl(x, 4) + " "+ arrEl(x, 5)

'Changing font and style of each cell
With .Cell(r, c).Range
            .Font.Name = "Times New Roman"
            .Font.Size = 8
            Debug.Print .Paragraphs(2).Range.Words.Last 
            'I've tried .Words.Count to tell he how many words
            'I've tried .Words(1) 
        End With
```

I am using Debug.Print to locate and isolate the storage condition (i.e. arrEl(x, 5) once it is in the cell in Word. I am encountering two problems:

1. .Words.Last is displaying the end-of-cell character ¤ even though the last word would hopefully read one of four storage conditions (-80C, RT, 2-8, -20C).
2. When I place the storage condition as the first word in the second paragraph I get incomplete portion of the storage condition. For example, only the "-" when I would like to have "-80" or only the "2" when I would like to have "2-8".

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is your goal to color code each storage condition on the printed labels? If so could you use Word's Find/Replace once for each storage condition? E.g., Find "-80C" and Replace with [BLUE] "-80C". Find "RT" and Replace with [GREEN] "RT".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say that the storage condition is in 'arrEl(x, 5)'

If this is so you need to change this line

```
.Cell(r, c).Range.Text =.Cell(r,c).Range.Text + arrEl(x, 3) + " "+ arrEl(x, 4) + " "+ arrEl(x, 5)
```

to

```
.Cell(r, c).Range.Text =.Cell(r,c).Range.Text & arrEl(x, 3) & " "+ arrEl(x, 4) & " "
Set my_range = .cell(r,c).range
my_range.collapse direction:=wdcollapseend
.Cell(r,c).range.text = .Cell(r,c).range.text & arrEl(x, 5)

my_range.end = .Cell(r,c).range.end
```

At this point my_range should include only the text from arrEl(x,5) so you can now apply the font formatting you desire to my_range.

You will of course need to insert a Dim my_range as Word.range in your code

Edit

To ensure we don't include any end of cell or paragraph markers in the range we can use the .MoveEndUntil method.  In the range examples provided the set of characters that denote the end of the rage are "CT8".  Thus we can do

```
my_range.MoveEndUntil cset:="CT8", count:=wdbackwards
```

Comment: I think this is the way to go. However, there is still one problem. when i try    Debug.Print my_range.Words(1)    it prints out the end-of-cell symbol that kinda looks like this: [] . Also,    my_range.Words  Count    displays 1. Why is it picking up that symbol?

Comment: @Astro  I edited my answer to add information of the MoveEndUntil range method.

Answer (score 0):

With Word VBA the following identifies the text in a table's cell:

```
ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(1,1).Range.Text
```

You can change the font characteristics of a word in a cell with:

```
ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(1,1).Range.Words(2).Font.ColorIndex = 3
```

or use the following for the entire text:

```
ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(1,1).Range.Font.ColorIndex = 3
```

If coding this from Excel then check that you are referencing Word, and its table(s), as appropriate.

---

You can modify, if needed, the text in a cell with

```
ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(1,1).Range.Text = "foo bar"
```

You can get the last word with

```
ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(1,1).Range.Words( _ 
    ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(1,1).Range.Words.Count - 1)
```

although this can be simplified with intermediate references. `Count - 1` is ignoring the ending cell marker (or whatever it is called).

Comment: Thank you Andy. The last suggestion definitely captured more of what I needed. However, in certain "words" it only captured a portion. For instance, 2-8 only displays 8, and -80 only displays 80. Is there a way to capture the entire expression (2-8, or -80). Can the 'delimiter' be a space? Or perhaps a different method instead of range.word?

Comment: You can store the entire Text in a variable and then manipulate this variable. You can use `Split` to split it. If you need to format part of the text which doesn't qualify as a "word" then you'll need to try and locate the specific Range of Characters that you want to format.

Comment: Just omit the phrase .Words(2) in my code to format the entire text of a cell.